# "Invalid bridge configuration" when set "notifications : true"

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to get event of connection and disconnection of every mqtt client.

Here is my config file

Is any way to achieve this ?

```
notifications true
listener 1883 192.168.22.54
protocol mqtt
listener 11883 192.168.22.54
protocol websockets
```

Answer (score 0):

The `notifications` configuration option is not for tracking normal client connections. It is only for use as part of a [bridge](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45143062652992) configuration and the notifications are only about the state of the bridge.

As you have added it to the config file but no other details about a bridge then the broker is rightly complaining that it is not part of a valid bridge configuration.

Comment: Is there any way to track normal client ?

Comment: I answered that in your other question, the best approach is to implement it yourself. (also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)